# "Play Game" tab on Facebook fanpage

Tags: facebook, button

I have a fanpage and a game app. The fanpage was created before the game, so I already have some likes, which I'd like to preserve. I need to add some tab or button which takes the user to my app (www.apps.facebook.com/myapp). There are no options about that on the fanpage's admin panel.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome to SO!

You have to build an HTML/PHP page with the button linking to your game page.
Also have in mind that you can use the same application (your game) with the Timeline App by serving the content from a different directory. You can setup this in the facebook developer app.

Some helpful resources:

**Page Tab Tutorial**
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/appsonfacebook/pagetabs/

**PHP SDK**
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/php/

**Javascript SDK**
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/